# Ruby file IO delimiters?

Tags: ruby, file-io, delimiter

I am trying to parse a text file that contains a variable number of words and numbers per line, like this:

```
foo 4.500 bar 3.00
1.3 3 foo bar
```

How can I read the file delimited by spaces instead of newlines? Is there some way I can set the `File("file.txt").foreach` method to use a spaces instead of newlines as a delimiter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
open('file.txt').read.split.each
```

to give you an iterator over space (or newline) separated words.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer will [**slurp**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189262/why-is-slurping-a-file-bad/25189286#25189286) the file, which can be a problem with large text files.

A better solution is [`IO.foreach`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach). It is idiomatic and will stream the file char by char:

```
File.foreach(filename," ") {|string| puts string}
```

Sample file containing `"this is an example"` results with

```
"this"
"is"
"an"
"example"
```

Answer (score 3):

File.open("file.txt").read.split(" ").each