# Splitting textfile into section with special delimiter line - python

Tags: python, file, delimiter, yield

I have an input file as such:

```
This is a text block start
This is the end

And this is another
with more than one line
and another line.
```

The desired task is to read the files by section delimited by some special line, in this case it's an empty line, e.g. [out]:

```
[['This is a text block start', 'This is the end'],
['And this is another','with more than one line', 'and another line.']]
```

I have been getting the desired output by doing so:

```
def per_section(it):
    """ Read a file and yield sections using empty line as delimiter """
    section = []
    for line in it:
        if line.strip('\n'):
            section.append(line)
        else:
            yield ''.join(section)
            section = []
    # yield any remaining lines as a section too
    if section:
        yield ''.join(section)
```

But if the special line is a line that starts with `#` e.g.:

```
# Some comments, maybe the title of the following section
This is a text block start
This is the end
# Some other comments and also the title
And this is another
with more than one line
and another line.
```

I have to do this:

```
def per_section(it):
    """ Read a file and yield sections using empty line as delimiter """
    section = []
    for line in it:
        if line[0] != "#":
            section.append(line)
        else:
            yield ''.join(section)
            section = []
    # yield any remaining lines as a section too
    if section:
        yield ''.join(section)
```

If i were to allow the `per_section()` to have a delimiter parameter, I could try this:

```
def per_section(it, delimiter== '\n'):
    """ Read a file and yield sections using empty line as delimiter """
    section = []
    for line in it:
        if line.strip('\n') and delimiter == '\n':
            section.append(line)
        elif delimiter= '\#' and line[0] != "#":
            section.append(line)
        else:
            yield ''.join(section)
            section = []
    # yield any remaining lines as a section too
    if section:
        yield ''.join(section)
```

**But is there a way so that i don't hard-code all possible delimiters?**

Comment: why not just pass in as parameters instead of hardcoding?

Comment: BTW, the @falsetru 's `per_section()` has been added to https://github.com/alvations/lazyme =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about pass a predicate?

```
def per_section(it, is_delimiter=lambda x: x.isspace()):
    ret = []
    for line in it:
        if is_delimiter(line):
            if ret:
                yield ret  # OR  ''.join(ret)
                ret = []
        else:
            ret.append(line.rstrip())  # OR  ret.append(line)
    if ret:
        yield ret
```

Usage:

```
with open('/path/to/file.txt') as f:
    sections = list(per_section(f))  # default delimiter

with open('/path/to/file.txt.txt') as f:
    sections = list(per_section(f, lambda line: line.startswith('#'))) # comment
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply do this:

```
with open('yorfileaname.txt') as f: #open desired file
    data = f.read() #read the whole file and save to variable data
    print(*(data.split('=========='))) #now split data when "=.." and print it 
    #usually it would ouput a list but if you use * it will print as string
```

Output:

```
content content
more content
content conclusion

content again
more of it
content conclusion

content
content
contend done
```

Comment: Usually it is a good idea to add an explanation on what your code does. This allows newer developers to understand how the coed works.

Comment: You are right, so i have explained everything as comments on my code.

Comment: Please do not do this if the file can be large. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189262/why-is-slurping-a-file-not-a-good-practice

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
from itertools import groupby

def per_section(s, delimiters=()):
    def key(s):
        return not s or s.isspace() or any(s.startswith(x) for x in delimiters)
    for k, g in groupby(s.splitlines(), key=key):
        if not k:
            yield list(g)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print list(per_section('''This is a text block start
This is the end

And this is another
with more than one line
and another line.'''))

    print list(per_section('''# Some comments, maybe the title of the following section
This is a text block start
This is the end
# Some other comments and also the title
And this is another
with more than one line
and another line.''', ('#')))

print list(per_section('''!! Some comments, maybe the title of the following section
This is a text block start
This is the end
$$ Some other comments and also the title
And this is another
with more than one line
and another line.''', ('!', '$')))
```

**Output:**

```
[['This is a text block start', 'This is the end'], ['And this is another', 'with more than one line', 'and another line.']]
[['This is a text block start', 'This is the end'], ['And this is another', 'with more than one line', 'and another line.']]
[['This is a text block start', 'This is the end'], ['And this is another', 'with more than one line', 'and another line.']]
```