# Read files line by line with \r, \n or \r\n as line separator

Tags: ruby

I want to process files line by line. However, these files have different line separators: `"\r"`, `"\n"` or `"\r\n"`. I don't know which one they use or which kind of OS they come from.

I have two solutions:

1. using bash command to translate these separators to `"\n"`.

   ```
   cat file |
   tr '\r\n' '\n' |
   tr '\r' '\n' |
   ruby process.rb
   ```
2. read the whole file and gsub these separators

   ```
   text=File.open('xxx.txt').read
   text.gsub!(/\r\n?/, "\n")
   text.each_line do |line|
     do some thing
   end
   ```

but the second solution is not good when the file is huge. See [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25189286/3675670). Is there any other ruby idiomatic and efficient solution?

Comment: This is a good question indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you first determine the line separator. I've assumed that you can do that by reading characters until you encounter "\n" or "\r" (or reach the end of the file, in which case we can regard "\n" as the line separator).  If the character "\n" is found, I assume that to be the separator; if "\r" is found I attempt to read the next character. If I can do so and it is "\n", I return "\r\n" as the separator. If "\r" is the last character in the file or is followed by a character other than "\n", I return "\r" as the separator.

```
def separator(fname)
  f = File.open(fname)
  enum = f.each_char
  c = enum.next
  loop do
    case c[/\r|\n/]
    when "\n" then break
    when "\r"
      c << "\n" if enum.peek=="\n"
      break
    end
    c = enum.next
  end
  c[0][/\r|\n/] ? c : "\n"
end
```

Then process the file line-by-line

```
def process(fname)
  sep = separator(fname)
  IO.foreach(fname, sep) { |line| puts line }
end
```

I haven't converted `"\r"` or `"\r\n"` to `"\n"`, but of course you could do that easily. Just open a file for writing and in `process` read each line and write it to the output file with the default line separator.

Let's try it (for clarity I show the value returned by `separator`):

```
fname = "temp"

IO.write(fname, "slash n line 1\nslash n line 2\n")
  #=> 30 
separator(fname)                                    
  #=> "\n" 
process(fname)
  # slash n line 1
  # slash n line 2

IO.write(fname, "slash r line 1\rslash r line 2\r", )
  #=> 30 
separator(fname)
  #=> "\r" 
process(fname)
  # slash r line 1
  # slash r line 2

IO.write(fname, "slash r slash n line 1\r\nslash r slash n line 2\r\n")
  #=> 48 
separator(fname)
  #=> "\r\n" 
process(fname)
  # slash r slash n line 1
  # slash r slash n line 2
```

Comment: I think you need to catch an error if you reach the end of the file before hitting the `\n` or `\r` ?  But thank you for the work you did!

Answer (score 0):

Using the index function (which gives you the first occurrence of a substring in a string and returns nil if it isn't found):

```
line_terminator = nil
if text.index("\r\n")
  puts 'Windows'
  line_terminator = "\r\n"
end
if line_terminator.nil? && text.index("\n")
  puts 'Unix'
  line_terminator = "\n"
end
line_terminator = "\r" if line_terminator.nil? # else it's legacy Mac, i.e. "\r"
```

I am not sure about the performance with very large files, but it works, and it's nice and short.