# Add new column to each row of a .csv in ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

I'm attempting to append a new column to each row of an existing csv file. The following code executes what I want:

```
csv_info = CSV.read("foo.csv")
csv_info.each do |info|
  info << new_object
end
```

giving me the following in memory when I use `pry`:

```
[[uuid0, account0, url0, new_object],
 [uuid1, account1, url1, new_object]]
```

This doesn't write to file since it's a `CSV.read` instead of a `CSV.open("foo.csv","w")`. When I attempt to write over the file with the `csv_info` object:

```
csv_info = CSV.read("foo.csv")
csv_info.each do |info|
  info << new_object
end
CSV.open("foo.csv", "w") do |old_csv|
  old_csv << csv_info
end
```

The file ends up as such:

```
[["[\"<uuid0>\", \"<account0>\", \"<url0>\", \"<new_object>\"]",
   "[\"<uuid1>\", \"<account1>\", \"<url1>\", \"<new_object>\"]"]]
```

How can I append without impacting the csv formatting?

Comment: `CSV#<<` expects a single row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`CSV#<<`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-i-3C-3C) expects a single row:

```
CSV.generate { |csv| csv << [1, 2, 3] }
#=> "1,2,3\n"

CSV.generate { |csv| csv << [1, 2, 3] << [4, 5, 6] }
#=> "1,2,3\n4,5,6\n"
```

but you're passing a two-dimenional array (which doesn't work as expected):

```
CSV.generate { |csv| csv << [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]] }
#=> "\"[1, 2, 3]\",\"[4, 5, 6]\"\n"
```

So instead of:

```
old_csv << csv_info
```

you need something like:

```
csv_info.each do |info|
  old_csv << info
end
```

Answer (score 4):

In your example you are reading the entire CSV and manipulating it in memory. Instead, I would suggest reading and modifying one row at a time, especially if the CSV file is large.

Here is how you could do the modification row-by-row to a temp file, then replace the original file with the temp file that was generated.

```
require "csv"
require "fileutils"
require "tempfile"

temp = Tempfile.new("csv")

CSV.open(temp, "w") do |temp_csv|
  CSV.foreach("foo.csv") do |orig|
    temp_csv << orig + ["new_object"]
  end
end

FileUtils.mv(temp, "foo.csv", :force => true)
```

Comment: Processing using [line-by-line is as fast as slurping the entire file, and is not prone to scalability issues](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25189262/128421). But, opening the file using `CSV.open` and assigning it to a temporary variable isn't the Ruby way. Use a block so Ruby will automatically close the output file when the block exits. So, +1 for the use of line-by-line IO and -1 for not using a block. Using a temp file is nice, but not necessary, just write to a new file and then `mv` it.

Comment: @theTinMan great feedback, thanks. I switched to block style for `CSV.open`. Not sure how I overlooked that!