# Read n lines above current line in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I've got a data file that looks like this:

```
Things
├── Foo
│  ├── 1. Item One
│  ├── 2. Item Two
│  ├── 3. Item Three
│  ├── 4. Item Four
│  ├── 5. Item Five
│  └── 6. Item Six
├── Bar
│  ├── 1. Item Seven
│  ├── 2. Item Eight
│  ├── 3. Item Nine
```

What I'm trying to do is find a certain string, the number associated with it, and also the subheading that is a part of ('Foo' or 'Bar')

It's pretty easy to grab the item and the number:

```
str = "Item One"
data.each_line do |line|
    if line =~ /#{str}/
        /(?<num>\d).\s(?<item>.*)/ =~ line
    end
end
```

But I'm not sure how to get the subheading. What I was thinking is that once I found the line, I could count up from that point using the number. Is there a readlines or a seek command or some such that could do this?

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Your method for processing the text file isn't scalable. You're assuming you can hold the entire file in memory, but everything grows over time, and eventually you'll encounter data that will not fit. Also, what you're doing is called 'slurping', which is slower and less efficient than reading a file line-by-line using `foreach`. I'd recommend rethinking how you want to do this, and consider line-by-line IO for speed and scalability. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189262/why-is-slurping-a-file-bad. Also become familiar with `$.` or `$INPUT_LINE_NUMBER` and the related variables.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I came up with below, this seems to work:

```
data = <<-EOF
Things
├── Foo
│  ├── 1. Item One
│  ├── 2. Item Two
│  ├── 3. Item Three
│  ├── 4. Item Four
│  ├── 5. Item Five
│  └── 6. Item Six
├── Bar
│  ├── 1. Item Seven
│  ├── 2. Item Eight
│  ├── 3. Item Nine
EOF

str = "Item One"
data.lines.each_with_index do |line, i|
    if /(?<num>\d)\.\s+#{str}/ =~ line
        /(?<var>\w+)/ =~ data.lines[i - (n = $~[:num]).to_i] 
        p [n, str, var] # ["1", "Item One", "Foo"]
    end
end
```

`(n = $~[:num])` is needed to store the captured value of `num` from

```
if /(?<num>\d)\.\s+#{str}/ =~ line
```

into a variable (say `n`) as [last match data](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html#method-c-last_match), represented by global variable `$~`, will get overwritten during the next regex match taking place in statement

```
/(?<var>\w+)/ =~ data.lines[i - (num = $~[:num]).to_i]
```

and unless we store it for later use we will lose the captured value `num`.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks. Wasn't aware of the with_index enumerator. Very nice.

Comment: You can replace the condition `line =~ /#{str}/` with `/(?<num>\d).\s#{str}/ =~ line` and get rid of `/(?<num>\d).\s(?<item>.*)/ =~ line`.

Comment: @sawa  That seems to give error `undefined local variable or method 'num' for main:Object (NameError)` inside the if block at `/(?<var>\w+)/ =~ data.lines[i - num.to_i]`

Comment: It is not calling `num` inside the condition. By the way, `\d` should become `\d+`, and `.` after `(?<num>\d)` should be escaped.

Comment: @sawa I mean error gets reported at `num.to_i`, I think `num` is getting defined outside the scope of if block if we do the way you suggest.  I did comment out the first line in `if` block assuming that `num` will be captured in `if` condition

Comment: I see. Maybe you can then refer to it as `$~[:num]`.

Comment: Okay, that works fine.  Will update the answer.  Thanks - now I need to figure out what `$~[:num]` does :-)

Comment: @sawa  I reverted partially back to original answer as I was unable to print `num` and `item` value after modifying the `if` condition

Comment: @sawa - Figured it out now, have updated the answer with explanation.  Thanks for valuable inputs

Comment: It isn't necessary to add "Update" sections in questions or answers. We can see what was changed if necessary. Instead, add the information in a way that makes sense and follows correct grammar. "PS" isn't necessary or particularly desirable; Answers are not conversations, they're a technical description of a solution like you'd see in a cookbook or an encyclopedia. Finally, there's no need or expectation of using headers like "Explanation". Look at the normal/usual formatting of questions and answers and follow that form. A common and consistent look and feel is the goal.

Comment: @theTinMan Got it. Thanks for the tips

Comment: Sorry to revisit this old thread, but I found that this has a weird exception when the list gets to item 10. In that case, `var` will return "10", instead of "Foo". This is not the case for numbers above 10, but just 10. Any guesses to why that's happening?

Comment: Oh! It's the \d+ note that @Sawa made several comments up. Perhaps the answer can be edited to reflect that?

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way (using @Wand's `data`):

```
LAZY_T = "├── " 
target = "Item Four"

str = data.split(/\n#{LAZY_T}/).find { |s| s =~ /\b#{target}\b/ }
str && [str[/[a-zA-Z]+/], str[/(\d+)\.\s#{target}\b/,1]]
  #=> ["Foo", "4"]
```

The first line pulls out the applicable part of the string (`"Foo"` or `"Bar"`), if there is one. The second line extracts the two desired elements.

Note:

```
LAZY_T.split('').map(&:ord)
  #=> [9500, 9472, 9472, 32]
```