# Comparison in reading lines from file

Tags: ruby, file, io

There are multiple ways to read lines from a file. Here are three:

```
# 1
File.open("temp.txt", "r") do |f|
  f.each_line { |l| puts l }
end

# 2
File.open("temp.txt", "r").each_line { |l| puts l }.close

# 3
File.readlines("temp.txt").each { |l| puts l }
```

1. Do those three methods correctly handle the file (i.e., close the file successfully afterwards)?
2. Is there a scenario in which one method surpasses the others (i.e., the given file is relatively large)? If so, what's the best practice?

Comment: You can answer this for yourself by reading the documentation and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189262/why-is-slurping-a-file-bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first way you show would take care of closing the file even when an error occurs, while the other two would not.

Comment: For the method 3, it doesn't need to close the file since `File.readlines("temp.txt")` returns an `Array`, right?

Comment: @JohnnySun This would read the whole files into memory, so you won't want to do this if you are processing a large file.

Comment: @JohnnySun `File.readlines` also handles file opening/closing. It even does not return file object you may close yourself.