# See if the beginning of a line matches a regex character

Tags: ruby, string

There are lines inside a file that contain `!`. I need all other lines. I only want to print lines within the file that do not start with an exclamation mark.

The line of code which I have written so far is:

```
unless parts.each_line.split("\n" =~ /^!/)
  # other bit of nested code
end
```

But it doesn't work. How do I do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We need a minimal example of data being checked and your expected output. See "[ask]" for the expected information for a question.

Answer (score 2):

As a start I'd use:

```
File.foreach('foo.txt') do |li|
  next if li[0] == '!'
  puts li
end
```

[`foreach`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/IO.html#method-c-foreach) is extremely fast and allows your code to handle any size file - "scalable" is the term. See "[Why is "slurping" a file not a good practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25189262/128421)" for more information.

[`li[0]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) is a common idiom in Ruby to get the first character of a string. Again, it's very fast and is my favorite way to get there, however consider these tests:

```
require 'fruity'

STR = '!' + ('a'..'z').to_a.join # => "!abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

compare do
  _slice { STR[0] == '!' }
  _start_with { STR.start_with?('!') }
  _regex { !!STR[/^!/] }
end

# >> Running each test 32768 times. Test will take about 2 seconds.
# >> _start_with is faster than _slice by 2x ± 1.0
# >> _slice is similar to _regex
```

Using [`start_with?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-start_with-3F) (or its String end equivalent [`end_with?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-end_with-3F)) is twice as fast and it looks like I'll be using `start_with?` and `end_with?` from now on.

Combine that with `foreach` and your code will have a decent chance of being fast and efficient.

See "[What is the fastest way to compare the start or end of a String with a sub-string using Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32976739)" for more information.

Comment: `start_with` is faster than `[]` because no temporary string is created?  Do you not prefer  `puts li if li[0] != '!'` or `puts li unless li[0] == '!'`? A small quibble: I suggest `IO.foreach`, since `foreach` is defined in `IO` (and  inherited by `File`). If readers want to look up the doc for `foreach` they may be puzzled when they can't find it in the docs for `File`.

Comment: I do not like `puts li` with a trailing conditional for this use as it's visual noise, I'd rather the `puts` be stand-alone. Yes, File does inherit from IO, but that's true of a lot of OO code. Since I'm reading a File I use `File.foreach`. If I was doing it from a different type of stream my choice might be different.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string#start_with` to find the lines that start with a particular string.

```
file = File.open('file.txt').read
file.each_line do |line|
  unless line.start_with?('!')
    print line
  end
end
```

You can also check the index of the first character

```
unless line[0] === "!"
```

You can also do this with Regex

```
unless line.scan(/^!/).length
```

Comment: Don't use `read` then `each_line`; It's not scalable at all. Instead use `foreach` which is faster. `start_with?` is faster than an equivalent regular expression. Using `scan(/^!/).length` isn't a good choice as that's not what `scan` is for. If you want to know whether the line starts with `!` then do that directly: `line[/^!/]` but remember, that's slower than using `start_with?`.