# Opening file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, syntax

Code sample 1:

```
def count_lines1(file_name)
  open(file_name) do |file|
    count = 0
    while file.gets
      count += 1
    end
    count
  end
end
```

Code sample 2:

```
def count_lines2(file_name)
  file = open(file_name)
  count = 0
  while file.gets
   count += 1
  end
  count
end
```

I am wondering which is the better way to implement the counting of lines in a file. In terms of good syntax in Ruby.

Comment: The biggest difference is that they're not equivalent; sample 1 closes the file at the end of the block. Beyond that it's opinion.

Comment: Use `file_name.readlines.count`

Comment: Don't use `readlines` unless you KNOW the file is small. `readlines` reads the file contents into memory as an Array. If the file is too big you'll have DOSed yourself. Instead use `foreach` which is faster with big files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> which is the better way to implement the counting of lines in a file.

Neither. Ruby can do it easily using `foreach`:

```
def count_lines(file_name)
  lines = 0
  File.foreach(file_name) { lines += 1 }
  lines
end
```

If I run that against my ~/.bashrc:

```
$ ruby test.rb
37
```

`foreach` is very fast and will avoid scalability problems.

Alternately, you could take advantage of tools in the OS, such as `wc -l` which were written specifically for the task:

```
`wc -l .bashrc`.to_i
```

which will return 37 again. If the file is huge, `wc` will likely outrun doing it in Ruby because `wc` is written in compiled code.

---

> You can also read in large chunks with read and count newline characters.

Yes, `read` will allow you to do that, but the scalability issue will remain. In my environment `read` or `readlines` can be a script killer because we often have to process files well into the tens of GB. There's plenty of RAM to hold the data, but the I/O suffers because of the overhead of slurping the data. "[Why is "slurping" a file not a good practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189262/why-is-slurping-a-file-bad/25189286#25189286)" goes into this.

An alternate way of reading in big chunks is to tell Ruby to read a set block size, count the line-ends in that block, looping until the file is read completely. I didn't test that method in the above linked answer, but in the past did similar things when I was writing in Perl and found that the difference didn't really improve things because it resulted in a bit more code. At that point, if all I was doing was counting lines, it'd make more sense to call `wc -l` and let it do the work as it'd be a lot faster for coding time and most likely in execution time.

Comment: You can also read in large chunks with `read` and count newline characters.

Comment: @ the Tin Man, thanks for the great answer that includes speed optimisation @tadman Cheers for the extra hint :)

Comment: Regarding using `read` and counting newlines, see the added section in the answer.

Comment: I meant using `read` with a fixed length limit, not read on the whole file. Using a smaller buffer, even 64KB, usually outperforms converting these blocks into individual strings. `wc` will be dramatically faster if available, but as always, *be very wary* when passing in arguments. Use the [open3 library](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html) and pass in arguments individually to avoid security problems. If not that, then use [`shellescape`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html#method-c-shellescape) on any arguments.