# Replace a string in csv using regex using ruby

Tags: ruby, string, csv

I have a csv files which has a columns test and id and values are :

```
"abc is 123 test", 1

"abc is 123 test", 2

"abc is 123 test", 3

"abc is 123 test", 4

"abc is 123 test", 5
```

I want to replace the `"abc is 123 test"` with `"abc is 567 test"`.

Note : Values `123` and `567` are dynamic values and with every new csv `123` gets changed, but string `"abc is <value> test"` always remain same.

Code i tried :

```
folder_path = "/home/test/files/"
f1 = folder_path + "abc.csv"
string_replace = "abc is 567 test"

file = IO.read(/home/test/files/abc.csv")
file_final = expected_file.gsub!("abc is".*, string_replace)
File.open(f1, 'w') { |f| f.write(file_final) }
```

I am getting the error:

> "ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments calling `*` (0 for 1)

Can anyone help ?

Comment: It can be more than 3 digits or less than 3 digits as well.

Comment: Are the numbers in "abc is 123 test" always three digits?

Comment: Using `read` and a regex is a bad idea unless you ALWAYS know the file will easily fit into memory. Anything over 2MB will slow your code in comparison to using line-by-line IO. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189262/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While technically the files are CSV, we can treat CSV files as text, since that's what they are. That makes it much easier to munge them when they're simple.

I'd start with:

```
File.open('csv.new', 'w') do |fo|
  DATA.each_line do |li|
    fo.puts li.sub('123', '456')
  end
end

__END__
"abc is 123 test", 1
"abc is 123 test", 2
"abc is 123 test", 3
"abc is 123 test", 4
"abc is 123 test", 5
```

Running it generates a file called "csv.new" which contains:

```
"abc is 456 test", 1
"abc is 456 test", 2
"abc is 456 test", 3
"abc is 456 test", 4
"abc is 456 test", 5
```

Instead of:

```
DATA.each_line do |li|
```

you'd want to open your original file using:

```
File.foreach("/home/test/files/abc.csv") do |li|
```

(`DATA` and `__END__` are a way to access sample data stored at the end of a Ruby script.)

`'123'` is prone to false-positive hits, and would change sub-strings:

```
'0123456'.sub('123', '456') # => "0456456"
```

to counter that, if there is any chance of sub-string matches you'd want to use a more intelligent search string; I'd use a regular expression:

```
'0123456'.sub(/\b123\b/, '456') # => "0123456"
```

which now checks to see if there's a word boundary surrounding `123`:

```
'0 123 456'.sub(/\b123\b/, '456') # => "0 456 456"
```

Since "123" could change, it'd make sense to assign it to a constant then substitute that into the pattern:

```
TARGET_STR = '123'

'0123456'.sub(/\b#{TARGET_STR}\b/, '456') # => "0123456"
'0 123 456'.sub(/\b#{TARGET_STR}\b/, '456') # => "0 456 456"
```

Because I'm using blocks with `open` and `foreach`, Ruby will automatically close the files once the blocks end, resulting in cleaner code, and better management of file handles.

Your code:

```
file = IO.read(/home/test/files/abc.csv")
file_final = expected_file.gsub!("abc is".*, string_replace)
File.open(f1, 'w') { |f| f.write(file_final) }
```

... is a ... mess.

- `read` is great for files you know will always be below 1MB in size. If you don't know that, especially if you're working in a production environment where files can be well into the GB range, using line-by-line IO is faster and safer as it sidesteps scalability issues. See "[Why is "slurping" a file not a good practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189262/why-is-slurping-a-file-not-a-good-practice)" for more information.
- We don't know what `expected_file` is, but it'll cause an error because it's undefined so Ruby would revolt because you used the `gsub!` method on a nil value.
- If `expected_file` is a String, `expected_file.gsub!` would mutate `expected_file`, but assigning the result to `file_final` wastes CPU. Instead reuse `expected_file`, or, better, use:

  ```
  file_final = expected_file.gsub(
  ```
- `"abc is".*` is an invalid parameter. Possibly `"abc is.*"` would be closer, but it appears you're reaching for a regular expression `/abc is.*/`, but that wouldn't be necessary to change the string, `/123/` or `'123'` would be sufficient.
- `gsub` would be overkill here too, since you only need a single replacement, so `sub` would be faster.
- Technically,

  ```
  File.open(f1, 'w') { |f| f.write(file_final) }
  ```

  will work, but it's much more easily written as

  ```
  File.write(f1, file_final)
  ```

---

You could reduce the code to:

```
File.write(
  'file.csv.new',
  File.read('file.csv').gsub(/\b123\b/, '456')
)
```

which, out of perverseness, could be written as:

```
File.write('file.csv.new', File.read('file.csv').gsub(/\b123\b/, '456'))
```

There'd be no improvement in speed, and instead it'd reduce readability.