# Python 3.7 : Hashing a binary file

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash, hashlib

I am trying to generate a hash for a given file, in this case the hash function got to a binary file (.tgz file) and then generated an error.  Is there a way I can read a binary file and generate a md5 hash of it?

The Error I am receiving is:

> ```
> buffer = buffer.decode('UTF-8') UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbc in position 10: invalid start byte
> ```

The source code is:

```
import hashlib

def HashFile(filename, readBlockSize = 4096):
    hash = hashlib.md5()

    with open(filename, 'rb') as fileHandle:

        while True:
            buffer = fileHandle.read(readBlockSize)

            if not buffer:
                break

            buffer = buffer.decode('UTF-8')                
            hash.update(hashlib.md5(buffer).hexdigest())

    return
```

I am using Python 3.7 on Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can tweak here.

You don't need to decode the bytes returned by `.read()`, because `md5()` is expecting `bytes` in the first place, not `str`:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> h = hashlib.md5(open('dump.rdb', 'rb').read()).hexdigest()
>>> h
'9a7bf9d3fd725e8b26eee3c31025b18e'
```

This means you can remove the line `buffer = buffer.decode('UTF-8')` from your function.

You'll also need to `return hash` if you want to use the results of the function.

Lastly, you need to pass the raw block of bytes to `.update()`, not its hex digest (which is a `str`); see the docs' [example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hash-algorithms).

Putting it all together:

```
def hash_file(filename: str, blocksize: int = 4096) -> str:
    hsh = hashlib.md5()
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        while True:
            buf = f.read(blocksize)
            if not buf:
                break
            hsh.update(buf)
    return hsh.hexdigest()
```

(The above is an example using a Redis .rdb dump binary file.)

Comment: I am trying to read the file (as I could potentially be hashing very large files) in 4k blocks.  Removing the decode I still get 'TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing'

Comment: That's because you're also calling `.hexdigest()`, which produces a `str`.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you! That has solved the issue.  It looks like I was using a 2.7 example.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pythonic way [NOT to slurp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189262/why-is-slurping-a-file-not-a-good-practice) binary-files:

```py
import hashlib
import io
import os


def hash_file(
        fpath: os.PathLike,
        digester_factory=hashlib.md5,
        chunk_size=io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE
) -> bytes: 
    digester = digester_factory()
    with open(fpath, "rb") as file:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: file.read(chunk_size), b''):
            digester.update(chunk)
    return digester.digest()

> hash_file("some/file.bin").hex()
b8e2d24ea2d0c722353e65f930153f85
> hash_file("some/file.bin").hex(' ', 2)
b8e2 d24e a2d0 c722 353e 65f9 3015 3f85
```

Some notes:

- use `iter(callable, sentinel)` to chunk input-file (and avoid ugly while-loops).
- consult Python interpreter about the preferred buffer-size, with `io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE`.
- support multiple hashing-functions with a factory pattern.
- prefer to return `digest() -> bytes` which supports eg `bytes.hex(sep, group_nbytes)`
  (instead of `hexdigest() -> str`) which maybe of aid to humans, when
  comparing binary numbers (though hashes are guaranteed to be completely different)
- TODO: refactor not to expect file-paths but binary-streams (type-hint: `typing.BinaryIO`), to support also reading STDIN, like:

  ```py
  > with open(fpath, `rb`) as file: hash_stream(file)
  > hash_stream(sys.stdin.buffer)
  ```