# Rails - file.readlines vs file.gets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory

I want to read lines of file from SFTP server.
There are more than 100000 lines in the file.

I am reading in 2 ways.

```
Net::SSH.start(setting.host, setting.user,
  {
    :key_data => [ key ],
    :keys => [],
    :keys_only => true
  }
) do |ssh|
  ssh.sftp.connect do |sftp|
    sftp.dir.foreach(src_dir) do |entry|
      if entry.name.include? today
        filename = "#{src_dir}/#{entry.name}"
        sftp.file.open(filename, "r") do |f|

          # Way 1
          f.readlines.each do |line|
            parse(line)
          end

          # Way 2
          while line = f.gets do
            parse(line)
          end
        end
      end
    end 
  end
end
```

I want to know which way is better in **memory usage**.

Comment: "[Why is “slurping” a file not a good practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189262)" goes into this. Reading a big file as an array can cause real problems as Ruby tries to allocate memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do the docs say? (Note that `File` is a subclass of `IO`. The methods `#readlines` and `#gets` are defined on `IO`.)

[`IO#readlines`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/IO.html#method-i-readlines):

> Reads all of the lines […], and returns them in an array.

[`IO#gets`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/IO.html#method-i-gets):

> Reads the next “line” from the I/O stream.

Thus, I expect the latter to be better in terms of memory usage as it doesn't load the entire file into memory.

Comment: Thank you, I thought so.

Comment: "as it doesn't load the entire file into memory" - this is a non-sequitur. The part you quoted does not say anything about what is loaded into memory. Only the behaviour. This is, therefore, dependent entirely on _what_ a particular IO object is.

Comment: Take `open-uri`, for example. It produces you an IO object, and yet a `open('http://example.com/file.txt').gets` will download the entire file before reading a first line from it. And StringIO objects hold their entire content in memory _by definition_.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, yes, you're right. By "latter" I was referring to the latter example in the question, related to `File`.

Comment: @fphilipe: ah, but in the question it's not a plain `File`, is it? It's whatever `Net::SFTP` gives us.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, yes, you are right :) In fact, the `file` variable is a [`Net::SFTP::Operations::File`](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-sftp/blob/master/lib/net/sftp/operations/file.rb) instance, which does not inherit from `IO`, but mimics it.

Comment: Digging deeper, this class will read 8192 bytes at a time as required ([source](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-sftp/blob/acbd1f7d435bb8bcc89a31b91bdfb6c8943df640/lib/net/sftp/operations/file.rb#L184)).

Comment: See "[What happens if you answered a question, questioner says thanks, but didn't accept your answer as correct?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109773)" and "[Do you feel dirty if you nudge new users to accept your answer when they indicate you've answered their question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14994)"

Answer (score 1):

Generally cycles are faster than blocks because of scope.

And arrays take much memory.

[`#readlines`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-readlines) reads all of the lines in ios, and returns them in an array.

[`#gets`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-gets) reads the next line from the I/O stream

I wrote little benchmark for file with 1387085 lines.

Also added [`::readlines`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-c-readlines) that reads the entire file specified by name as individual lines, and returns those lines in an array and [`::foreach`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-c-foreach) that executes the block for every line in the named I/O port.

```
require 'benchmark/ips'
require 'benchmark/memory'

@path = File.join(__dir__, 'file.txt')

def open_readlines
  File.open(@path, 'r') do |f|
    f.readlines.each do |line|
      line << 'www'
    end
  end
end

def open_gets
  File.open(@path, 'r') do |f|
    while line = f.gets do
      line << 'www'
    end
  end
end

def readlines
  File.readlines(@path).each do |line|
    line << 'www'
  end
end

def foreach
  File.foreach(@path) do |line|
    line << 'www'
  end
end

%i[ips memory].each do |benchmark|
  puts benchmark

  Benchmark.send(benchmark) do |x|
    x.report('::open #readlines') { open_readlines }
    x.report('::open #gets') { open_gets }
    x.report('::readlines') { readlines }
    x.report('::foreach') { foreach }

    x.compare!
  end
end
```

And results are:

```
ips
Warming up --------------------------------------
   ::open #readlines     1.000  i/100ms
        ::open #gets     1.000  i/100ms
         ::readlines     1.000  i/100ms
           ::foreach     1.000  i/100ms
Calculating -------------------------------------
   ::open #readlines      0.575  (± 0.0%) i/s -      3.000  in   5.397538s
        ::open #gets      0.746  (± 0.0%) i/s -      4.000  in   5.381583s
         ::readlines      0.570  (± 0.0%) i/s -      3.000  in   5.434956s
           ::foreach      0.826  (± 0.0%) i/s -      5.000  in   6.057936s

Comparison:
           ::foreach:        0.8 i/s
        ::open #gets:        0.7 i/s - 1.11x  slower
   ::open #readlines:        0.6 i/s - 1.44x  slower
         ::readlines:        0.6 i/s - 1.45x  slower

memory
Calculating -------------------------------------
   ::open #readlines   822.274M memsize (     8.424k retained)
                         2.774M objects (     1.000  retained)
                        50.000  strings (     0.000  retained)
        ::open #gets   810.638M memsize (     0.000  retained)
                         2.774M objects (     0.000  retained)
                        50.000  strings (     0.000  retained)
         ::readlines   822.274M memsize (     0.000  retained)
                         2.774M objects (     0.000  retained)
                        50.000  strings (     0.000  retained)
           ::foreach   810.638M memsize (     0.000  retained)
                         2.774M objects (     0.000  retained)
                        50.000  strings (     0.000  retained)

Comparison:
           ::foreach:  810638012 allocated
        ::open #gets:  810638052 allocated - 1.00x more
         ::readlines:  822274324 allocated - 1.01x more
   ::open #readlines:  822274364 allocated - 1.01x more
```

Comment: Comparing runtimes is interesting, but not what was being asked :) Run it through a memory profiler. This one, for example: https://github.com/michaelherold/benchmark-memory

Comment: It gives the same results (the same memory size) :)

Comment: "the same memory size" - that's weird.

Comment: What about [IO::foreach](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/IO.html#method-c-foreach), which is often the method of choice when reading a file line-by-line, in part because it returns an enumerator when no block is given, thereby permitting chaining to another method?

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks, I added this method to comparison